# Sitecore item.IsClone vs item.IsItemClone

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

What is the difference between `item.IsClone` vs `item.IsItemClone`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`item.IsClone` does a quick check for a cloning relation for the context language.

`item.IsItemClone` is a little more sophisticated; it will also do the check for the current language, but if there is no cloning relation found, it will check again for all other language versions. Also, the result of this property is cached in the DataCache.

I think in most cases you are best off using `IsItemClone`.